# Codeigniter: recuperar valores do array fora do loop

Tags: array, codeigniter, foreach

Estou com um problema para armazenar os valores do array no código abaixo:

```
public function get_submenu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent' => 0));

    foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    endforeach;

    if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

Dentro do loop a variável $cat_id armazena corretamente os valores de minha query, quando dou um echo em:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row):
    $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    echo $cat_id;
endforeach;
```

Mas se o echo é fora do loop, assim:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row):
    $cat_id = $row->category_id;
endforeach;

echo $cat_id;
```

O que retorna é apenas o último id armazenado.

Eu preciso armazenar todos os valores do array $cat_id para recuperar no bloco if subsequente:

```
if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
```

Como faço isso?

Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que toda vez que ele fizer o loop o último valor será armazenado sempre, portanto ao fazer isso toda vez que o loop rodar ele irá sobrepor o valor anterior. Para criar um array você deve fazer da seguinte forma.

```
$cat_id = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        $cat_id[] = $row->category_id;
    endforeach;
```

Explicando ainda mais seu código:

*Dentro do loop a variável $cat_id armazena corretamente os valores de minha query, quando dou um echo em:*

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row):
    $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    echo $cat_id;
endforeach;
```

O `echo` está dentro do `foreach` e será chamado toda vez que houver uma execução no `foreach`.

Neste trecho do seu código, se não me engano o correto seria utilizar `$this->db->where_in()`, por se tratar de um `array`.

```
if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where_in('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $this->db->where('category_id  !=', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
```

Comment: Obrigado Diego.